# get row values till same condition appears in the record in sql

Tags: sql, mariadb

```
id | amount
-----------
1  | 100  |
2  | 0    |
3  | 0    |
4  | 200  |
5  | 0    |
6  | 0    |
```

I have this table in which the value column will have frequent values greater than 0. I am trying to figure out a SQL query that will print values between the first greater than 0 value and the second greater than 0 value.

for the above table, the output will be

```
id | amount
-----------
1  | 100  |
2  | 0    |
3  | 0    |
```

I am not getting what kind of condition will be applied to achieve this. I have tried the `Group By` but it only counts the total number of the same value.

I also thought of giving each value a unique number such as below

```
id | Serial number | amount
---------------------------
1  |       1       | 100  |
2  |       1       | 0    |
3  |       1       | 0    |
4  |       1       | 200  |
5  |       1       | 0    |
6  |       1       | 0    |
```

But again I was unable to display the data with query since I am confused about how to do it.

Comment: Which MySQL version are you using?

Comment: @jarlh 10.3.32-MariaDB-cll-lve

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
WITH v AS (
 SELECT *, SUM(amount) OVER(ORDER BY id ASC) sum_amount, MAX(amount) OVER(ORDER BY id ASC) max_amount
 FROM t
)
SELECT id, amount
FROM v
WHERE sum_amount > 0 AND sum_amount = max_amount
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=6bbe57c4f23d689c50947aa77c501fb8)

Look at this query

```
 SELECT *, SUM(amount) OVER(ORDER BY id ASC) sum_amount, MAX(amount) OVER(ORDER BY id ASC) max_amount
 FROM t
```

With result set:

```
+----+--------+------------+------------+
| id | amount | sum_amount | max_amount |
+----+--------+------------+------------+
|  1 |    100 |        100 |        100 |
|  2 |      0 |        100 |        100 |
|  3 |      0 |        100 |        100 |
|  4 |    200 |        300 |        200 |
|  5 |      0 |        300 |        200 |
|  6 |      0 |        300 |        200 |
|  7 |      0 |        300 |        200 |
|  8 |    300 |        600 |        300 |
|  9 |      0 |        600 |        300 |
+----+--------+------------+------------+
```

`SUM`, `MAX` in window function will calculate the value up to the current row as per `ORDER BY id ASC`

- `sum_amount > 0` finds the first row with amount greater than zero
- `sum_amount = max_amount` excludes another row with amount greater than zero and the rows after that, because when reaching such a row, the sum is always greater than the max

Comment: I am not trying to add the values. I just want to display the data in between the condition. AS I understood from your query, it tries to sum the amount which is not required.

Comment: @tru_shar query is not returning the sum, it is just a method to get expected result

Comment: Can you explain the query?

Comment: @tru_shar updated, hope it's clear and helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I assume I don't know when the first positive value appears first. Using the window function and 'case when' logic I build a positive values counter by means of which I can  pull out all the records between my x positive value (x representing position) and y positive value (y representing position appearing after x).

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=cd95890e6e795f4209cf8b42773e9937)

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (id INT PRIMARY KEY,amount INT NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES
(1,0 ),(2,100),(3,0),(4,0),(5,200),(6,0),(7,0),(8,300),(9,0);
    

 SELECT 
 *, sum(amount_check) over (order by id asc)  as positive_value_counter
 FROM
    (SELECT *, 
    CASE WHEN amount > 0 then 1 else 0 end as amount_check
    FROM tbl) s   

+----+--------+---------------+------------------------+
| id | amount | amount_check  | positive_value_counter |
+----+--------+---------------+------------------------+
|  1 |      0 |        0      |        0               |
|  2 |    100 |        1      |        1               |
|  3 |      0 |        0      |        1               |
|  4 |      0 |        0      |        1               |
|  5 |    200 |        1      |        2               |
|  6 |      0 |        0      |        2               |
|  7 |      0 |        0      |        2               |
|  8 |    300 |        1      |        3               |
|  9 |      0 |        0      |        3               |
+----+--------+---------------+------------------------+
 
SELECT *
FROM
    (SELECT *, sum(amount_check) over (order by id asc)  as positive_value_counter
        FROM
        (SELECT *, 
        CASE WHEN amount > 0 then 1 else 0 end as amount_check
        FROM tbl) s
    ) m
WHERE
positive_value_counter >= 1 and positive_value_counter < 2
              
+----+--------+---------------+------------------------+
| id | amount | amount_check  | positive_value_counter |
+----+--------+---------------+------------------------+
|  2 |    100 |        1      |        1               |
|  3 |      0 |        0      |        1               |
|  4 |      0 |        0      |        1               |
+----+--------+---------------+------------------------+
```